# Is opening multiple file handles on the same file at the same time a acceptable practice in python?

Tags: python, io

For example:

```
bedpath = "/tmp/bedtest"
with open(bedpath, "rb") as fh1, open(bedpath, "rb") as fh2:
    fh1.seek(3)
    fh2.seek(5)
    for i in range(3):
        b1 = fh1.read(1)
        b2 = fh2.read(1)
        # do something with b1 and b2
```

If not, why?

Comment: You can open multiple file handles on a file, yes. Take into account that a read buffer on one object may not see changes written via another.

Comment: It's no better or worse than doing so in any other language.  It's mildly inelegant and consumes a tiny amount of extra kernel resources, but it's a perfectly acceptable thing to do if it makes your problems easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done this to read the same file in multiple threads and it works fine. If you are trying to push more speed, though, chances are you'll be i/o bound anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

For reading files this is acceptable, especially, if you need multiple seek positions.

For modifying the file - better do not try that (comments reacting to MartijnPieters).

- beginners (not meaning you) often attempt to read and modify a file at the same moment, not understanding, that text line is not how is file stored on a disk. This is what I call simple failure.
- you can try modifying a file while reading it or modify it from multiple file descriptors. But this is quite complex and mostly can be avoided by something, what is few orders of magnitude simpler to understand and maintain.

Comment: For modifying the file it is *not* simple failure, if you understand the buffering semantics of the file objects you are working with. The Python 3 `io` library makes those semantics quite clear and accessible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you please elaborate on "semantics of the file objects" into an answer?

Comment: @qed: If you understand that Python 3 I/O (or using `io.open()` in Python 2) uses a [`BufferedIOBase` derived object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) then you also know that reading fills a buffer. Writing to the disk similarly uses buffers. In-memory buffers can be out-of-sync if file contents change.